# postgresql and Delete statement violates foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I have a problem with my delete statement.

I have two tables:

```
table vehicule_loan(
    vehicule TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

table vehicule_uid (
    id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    vehicule TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES vehicule_loan(vehicule) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

When I delete a `vehicule` from the table `vehicule_loan` I want that referencing rows in the table `vehicule_uid` are kept.

But when I try to delete one I get this error:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "vehicule_loan" violates foreign key constraint "vehicule_uid_vehicule_fkey" on table "vehicule_uid"
```

I think I  understand the error:
After I delete a `vehicule` from the table `vehicule_loan`, the `vehicule` in `vehicule_uid` would point to nothing.

But is there a way to keep the rows in `vehicule_uid` ?

Comment: in the foreign key declaration you have `vehicule(vehicule)` but there's no vehicule table!

Comment: @user1089668, I undertand this is a typo because in error you can see that "vehicule_uid"  references "vehicule_loan".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should allow `NULL` values in the foreign key attribute and define the foreign key constraint as `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

I quote chapter [*5.3. Constraints* from the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html):

> There are two other options: SET NULL and SET DEFAULT. These cause the
>   referencing columns to be set to nulls or default values,
>   respectively, when the referenced row is deleted.

Could look like this:

```
table vehicule_uid (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    vehicule text REFERENCES vehicule_loan(vehicule) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

With this setting, when you delete a row in `vehicule_loan` all referencing rows in `vehicule_uid` remain in database.

Comment: You are copying the error from the question. The fk constraint references a table `vehicule` while you talk about a table `vehicule_loan`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, thaks about your appointment. Fixed now in my answer. OP and I have change `vehicule_loan` to `vehicle`, but, as you can see, this is not the major issue, only a typo (typographical error). Raise error also talks about `vehicule_uid` table, that means that foreign key in real database is well writed. You agree?

Comment: +1 I agree and I think your answer is just what the OP needs. I took the liberty to apply minor improvements and also fixed the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, thanks about answer improvements, you have rewrote answer. You look so good for 92 (your age in your profile).

Comment: Daily training with PostgreSQL keeps a man's skin smooth. I am sure you knew that? :)

Comment: May be in Austria ;) Nice to meet you @ErwinBrandstetter.